# gem install mysql not working. But i'm able to connect to mysql -u root -p

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I'm using ubuntu based backtrack OS. I have mysql installed and i'm able to stop, start, connect to mysql.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

works fine and able to create database and could be able to see data in /var/lib/mysql

```
root@bt:/usr/share/mysql# gem install mysql2
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.11.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Same case with `gem install mysql`

```
root@bt:/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/mysql-2.8.1# sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.2 extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql
/usr/bin/mysql: unknown option '--cflags'
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.2
    --with-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Problem is alteast to specify as below command, I couldn't able to find `mysql_config` file.

`gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=<PATH>` which i couldn't find.

Please help me fixing this issue. Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164294/rails-mysql-gem-problem-on-ubuntu ?

Comment: No... The link you provided doesn't help.. that's why created with all various problems..

Comment: Error messages say to check `mkmf.log`... have you checked it?

Comment: Couldn't find that log file.

Answer (score 3):

try :

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
gem install mysql2
```

Comment: When i'm trying to install libmysqlclient-dev, i'm getting below error. `libmysqlclient-dev`: Depends `libmysqlclient16 (=5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10)` but `5.1.63ubuntu0.10.04.1` is to be installed. E: broken packages..

Comment: it seems you upgraded ubuntu, you can try the followings:

`sudo killall mysqld`
`sudo killall mysqld_safe`

Then 
`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server`
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5`

Answer (score 0):

to find mysql_config just use:

```
locate mysql_config
```

and choose from the list the appropriate path.